Dynamic Power BI line chart MAX X axis
For a dashboard I am currently running into a challenge, where I need to cap off a line chart if a certain value is selected.
I have a line chart with:

Multiple lines for all years 2018-2024
Cumulative Sales as a value
Month nr on the X axis.

The Cum. Sales is based on the Sales column. The Sales are sourced from 3 different Channels, which can be filtered. Let's call the sources A/B/C for now.
The challenge is that sources B and C are up-to-date, whereas source A is (almost always) 1 month behind. The problem with the current Cumulative Sales is that it shows the wrong value in the most recent month, as it'll add 0 for the A Channel.
The required output would be to cap off the line chart if A (or more) are filtered, to show the line chart up until it's max known Sales date.
The other way around I want it to show the max Month if A isn't filtered. So it shows the max month for B and C respectively.
How can I fix this? do you need anything from me to help further answer my question?
Kind regards,
Daniël
Currently I have a Visual level Flag indicator as follows:

Max Month Flag =
var _A=IF(ISFILTERED('Slicer Test'[channel]) && {"A"} in VALUES('Slicer Test'[channel]),1,0)
var _month_A=MONTH(MAXX(FILTER(ALL('Table'),[Channel]="A"),[Date]))
RETURN SWITCH(TRUE(),
_A=1 && MAX(dates[Month])<= _month_A,1,
_A=0,1,0)
`

It correctly returns a 0 for the month where it has no data, but it does so for each year. The required outcome is that it returns a 1 for each month (including previous years), up until the most recent month. Now it returns 0's for each year. ex: It returns a a 0 for 2024-03 as expected, but also for 2023-03 up until 2023-12
